# Twilio conversation WhastApp duplicate messages

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am doing a Chat conversation with the Conversation API of Twilio and the JavaScript SDK of conversation for the webchat integration, the problem is when the Whastapp Client number send a message to the Whastapp Twilio Number, the client received the same message that was sent

Does anyone has have this problem?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations

Comment: Can you share any relevant code for this issue?

Comment: Was a problem with the Twilio infrastructure with my country

Comment: Oh weird! Hope it's sorted now!

Comment: @philnash yes, it was, in this Month (June 2021) the issue was already resolved.